# Use Matrix4x4 to transform points in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to convert some Vector3 points into 2d, projecting them onto a plane just like a camera would, with perspective.
I am starting with 3d points, a camera position and look direction, and fov.
My attempt:

```
void Update()
    {
        Matrix4x4 proj = Matrix4x4.LookAt(FakeCam.transform.position, Vector3.zero, FakeCam.transform.up) *
            Matrix4x4.Perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);

        for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            var point = proj.MultiplyPoint(Points[i]);
            Dots.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(point.x, 0, point.z));
        }

        Dots.Draw(transform.localToWorldMatrix);
    }
```

The LookAt matrix seems to work as expected here. If I only use the LookAt matrix, I get my object shown (with an orthographic projection). If I add the perspective matrix, it is twisted in the middle (the back face of the cube is rotated 180 ??)

[image]

Comment: Absolutely no matrix expert .. shouldn't be the protection matrix of the camera already be enough? It basically does this, take the world coords and convert them to a 2D rendering.. or am I totally confused? ^^

Comment: I dont actually have a camera. Just a view position and direction

Comment: What I mean is the projection matrix from `Matrix4x4.Perspective` .. this is basically what `Camera` is internally using as well

Comment: Oh yes, but how is it using it? I only get this twisted cube...

Comment: Also if you remove the `LookAt` and only use the perspective matrix?

Comment: Also `Dots.Draw(transform.localToWorldMatrix);` might be an issues.. I don't think your positions are in local space .. maybe you need to add the `transform.worlsToLocalMatrix` before setting the positions

Comment: Removing the lookat matrix gives the twisted cube